# GeoJSON .NET with Google Maps in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I am trying to create and load geoJSON data into Google Maps using the [GeoJSON .NET](https://github.com/jbattermann/GeoJSON.Net) library using ASP.NET MVC5 though I am doing something wrong somewhere.

Using the example code posted on the GitHub site my controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult GetGeoJson()
{
    var point = new GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.Point(
                    new GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.GeographicPosition(45.79012, 15.94107));
    var featureProperties = new Dictionary<string, object> { {"Name", "Foo"} };
    var model = new GeoJSON.Net.Feature.Feature(point, featureProperties);
    var serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.Indented,
               new JsonSerializerSettings
               {
                   ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                   NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore 
               });

    return Json(serializedData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And my view is as follows:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Map";
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=foobar"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {

        var centerPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(53.710921, -1.626776);

        var mapOptions = {
            center: centerPoint,
            zoom: 12
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        map.data.loadGeoJson('/Home/GetGeoJson');

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<div id="map-canvas">

</div>
```

When I load the page and check the console in chrome I have the following error:

> Uncaught InvalidValueError: not a Feature or FeatureCollection

If I go to my Action within the brower it outputs the following:

```
"{\r\n  \"geometry\":
{\r\n    \"coordinates\": [\r\n      15.94107,\r\n      45.79012\r\n    ],
\r\n    \"type\": \"Point\"\r\n  },
\r\n  \"properties\": {\r\n    \"name\": \"Foo\"\r\n  },
\r\n  \"type\": \"Feature\"\r\n}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A related SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720843/ajax-call-to-get-geojson-data-from-asp-net-mvc-controller) gave me the answer. I needed to change the return in my controller from

```
return Json(serializedData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

to

```
return Content(serializedData, "application/json");
```

as the JsonResult was also serializing the serialized data.